# Setting multiple Alarms without user interaction

Tags: android

I am trying to set multiple system alarms from my app.

I have this code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
                i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, 9);
                i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, 37);
                startActivity(i);
```

This is opening a system window where the user has to press create alarm.
Is there a way to create multiple alarms without user interaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Flag [EXTRA_SKIP_UI](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/AlarmClock.html#EXTRA_SKIP_UI) in your intent

```
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_SKIP_UI, true);
```